# Google Calendar nested JSON -- Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, nested, google-calendar-api

I'm trying extract selected data from Google calendar to display it in a form using ng-repeat on client side. On sever side, I'm unable to loop through the data due to lack of understanding of nested

Simplified calendar JSON

```
const calendarList = {
items: [{
    summary: 'ABC',
    start: [{ datetTime: '2017-12-10T01:40:18.000Z'}], 
    attendees: [{ displayName: 'John'}]
},
{
    summary: 'DEF',
    start: [{ datetTime: '2017-12-11T01:40:18.000Z'}], 
    attendees: [{ displayName: 'Jane'}, { displayName: 'Mary'}]
}]
};
```

First layer is to get to **items** inside the object, from **items**, extract **summary**, **start (dateTime)** and **attendees (displayName)**. There is a possibility of multiple attendees

```
console.log(calendarList.items[0].summary); //ABC
console.log(calendarList.items[0].start.dateTime); //2017-12-10T01:40:18.000Z
console.log(calendarList.items[0].attendees[0].displayName); //John
```

First I convert the object to array, from there I can access **items**

```
 var calendararray = Object.keys(calendarList)
 console.log(calendararray)

    // [ 'kind',
    // 'etag',
    // 'summary',
    // 'updated',
    // 'timeZone',
    // 'accessRole',
    // 'defaultReminders',
    // 'nextSyncToken',
    // 'items' ]
```

From **items** I wrote a for loop and this is where it didn't work. The error message is **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

```
for(var i = 0; i < calendararray.items.length; i++)
    {
        var items = calendarList.items[i];
        newGcal.summary += items.summary;
        newGcal.datetime += items.start.datetime;

        for(var j = 0; j < items.attendees.length; j++)
        {
            var attendees = items.attendees[j];
            newGcal.attendees += attendees.displayName;
        }
    }
```

I've console.log **calendararray.items[0]** and there is a list including **summary**, **start** and **attendees**

```
console.log(calendararray.items[0])

[ 'kind',
  'etag',
  'id',
  'status',
  'htmlLink',
  'created',
  'updated',
  'summary',
  'description',
  'location',
  'creator',
  'organizer',
  'start',
  'end',
  'iCalUID',
  'sequence',
  'attendees',
  'guestsCanInviteOthers',
  'privateCopy',
  'reminders' ]
```

Please any help or advice

Comment: Instead of for(var i = 0; i < calendararray.items.length; i++) should it not be for(var i = 0; i < calendarList.items.length; i++) ? calendararray is just an array of keys

Comment: This won't work @cdoshi because calendarList is an object so it'll return that length is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I convert the object to array, from there I can access **items**

That's where you went wrong. Don't convert anything to anything; you can easily work with the data directly as it is.

`.forEach()` is helpful for this, so you don't have to write error-prone `for` loops.

Here's an example that lists all the data in your simplified `calendarList`. You should be able to take it from here for the other related items in the actual data.

I also reformatted your `calendarList` data a bit to make the object/array relationships more clear:

```js
const calendarList = {
    items: [
        {
            summary: 'ABC',
            start: [
                { datetTime: '2017-12-10T01:40:18.000Z' }
            ],
            attendees: [
                { displayName: 'John' }
            ]
        },
        {
            summary: 'DEF',
            start: [
                { datetTime: '2017-12-11T01:40:18.000Z' }
            ],
            attendees: [
                { displayName: 'Jane' },
                { displayName: 'Mary' }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

calendarList.items.forEach( function( item ) {
    console.log( 'summary:', item.summary );
    item.start.forEach( function( dt ) {
        console.log( '  start:', dt.datetTime );
    });
    item.attendees.forEach( function( attendee ) {
        console.log( '  attendee:', attendee.displayName );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Geary! This is super helpful! I manage to get it working. Now the challenge is saving many items in MongoDB